# tensorflow save/restore queue

Tags: python, tensorflow, queue

How can I use a saved graph to make a prediction when the graph is feed from a queue?

This is how I define the graph and the enqueue/ dequeue:

```
X_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, FLAGS.max_words], name="X_placeholder")
Y_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, output_classes], name="Y_placeholder")
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=1000, dtypes=[tf.int32, tf.int32])
enqueue_op = q.enqueue_many([X_placeholder, Y_placeholder], name="enque_op")
X, Y = q.dequeue()
.......
```

This is how I run the enqueue and training:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={X_placeholder: X_array, Y_placeholder: Y_array})
        for i in range(100):
            sess.run(optimize, feed_dict=feed)

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

And this is how I save the graph:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path)
gd = sess.graph.as_graph_def()
converted_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, gd, ["prediction"])
tf.train.write_graph(converted_graph_def, FLAGS.export_dir, 'model' + s + '.pb', as_text=False)
```

How can I run the enqueue op after importing this graph?

I tried restoring the queue tensor but I can't call "q.enqueue_many" on it.

```
q = graph.get_tensor_by_name('queue/fifo_queue:0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, you can just add the enqueue operation in the saved graph.

```
converted_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, gd, ["prediction", "enqueue_op"])
```